# Loading a .sav file in google collab

Tags: python

Im creating a simple python program in google colab wherein i have to import/load a .sav file in the code which is saved at my google drive. i tried mounting google drive locally, installing pyreadstat, but it still shows the error

> "PyreadstatError: File /sales.sav does not exist!"

my code:

```
# Machine Problem 2

import pandas as pd
import os 

#Loading a .Sav file and assigning it to a variable
#We will open and work on "sales.sav"
df = pd.read_spss("/sales.sav")
```

Comment: Try prepending a dot in from of the file path `df = pd.read_spss("./sales.sav")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Pyreadstat cannot read files on remote drives, network drives, etc. You will need to somehow move the file to a local drive.